# In partial view: "The model item passed into the dictionary is of type"

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I lack understanding of some basic MVC concepts, despite all my searching.

I created an MVC project in Visual Studio, which contains the partial view _LogOnPartial.shtml.  I just want to access information within the view pertaining to the user, to put in a user dropdown menu.  When I try to put this at the top of the partial view cshtml page I get the above error:

```
@model MyProject_MVC.Models.UserRepository
```

When I try this I also get an error:

```
@Html.Partial("_LogOnPartial", MyProject_MVC.Models.UserRepository)
```

'MyProject_MVC.Models.UserRepository' is a 'type', which is not valid in the given context

Comment: Your model really shouldn't be a repository, but the result of a repository, e.g. the "model".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to provide an instance of `MyProject_MVC.Models.UserRepository` to the partial view. `_LogOnPartial` is strongly-typed to that type. It lets you access its public members at compile time and decide how you can display it in your view.

If you want to use your own type in that view, first you have to change the type that is strongly-typed to it.

```
@model MyProject_MVC.Models.UserRepository
```

Then you have to create an instance of that type in your action method and pass it to the view as the model or a property of the model.

```
public ActionResult LogOn()
{
    return View(new UserRepository());
}
```

Now you can access this instance as Model object in your view.

```
@Html.Partial("_LogOnPartial", Model);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still lacking some basic understanding apparently.  I do not understand returning UserRepository in the action method of the Login page, when every page is different and has its own data model.  I have Gallery page, for example (and lots of others), where I want to return Gallery data, not UserRepository, to the View.  This is where I'm very confused.

Comment: Plus, what if I just want to call a method from the cshtml, like GetUserNotes(userid); instead of returning everything at once in a data model?  I know it seems inefficient, but is that also not allowed in MVC?  Thanks.

Comment: @Dave: it looks like you need to spend some time trying to understand how MVC works. It's full of basic tutorials out there.

Comment: I've tried, as indicated above, and am just asking, how can you return one set of data to your main page, and another set of data to the partial view, which in this case is a user dropdown menu.  It's probably so incredibly basic that nobody is even mentioning it.

Comment: I think that object composition is what you are asking for.

Answer (score 2):

`@model _LogOnPartial.Models.UserRepository` should probably be: `@model MyProject_MVC.Models.UserRepository`

and for the last part, you have to provide and instance of the type UserRepository as the second parameter, not the type itself.

Comment: The first line was a typo, sorry, thanks for letting me know.